# Type com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity is defined multiple times In Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I made Android studio Plugin (aar) because I want to use Beacon scanner in my Unity Project.
But In Unity I have several errors:

> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\UnityExample\navigation_qlearning\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\build.transforms\cd44b8741c473d7b1616510ae3ee97fa\classes\classes.dex: D8: Type com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity is defined multiple times: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\UnityExample\navigation_qlearning\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\build.transforms\cd44b8741c473d7b1616510ae3ee97fa\classes\classes.dex, C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\UnityExample\navigation_qlearning\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\intermediates\external_libs_dex\release\out\classes.dex
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:

And this is my Android studio 'build.gradle'(app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        //applicationId "com.example.plugin0321_1"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        //versionCode 1
        //versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    //freeDebugRuntimeOnly fileTree (dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compileOnly fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```